# C# WebApi + Angular 4 Set-Cookie doesn't save cookies

Tags: javascript, c#, angular, cookies, asp.net-web-api

I'm doing an http request to my API that is supposed to send me back two cookies with the Set-Cookie Header.

It seems that the cookie is correctly send back for this Init Request but they are not saved in Chrome, so for later requests the cookies are not sent.

My Init response headers are :

```
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials:true
Access-Control-Allow-Headers:content-type
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:http://localhost:4200
Cache-Control:no-cache
Content-Length:0
Date:Thu, 20 Apr 2017 09:25:45 GMT
Expires:-1
Pragma:no-cache
Server:Microsoft-IIS/8.0
Set-Cookie:ASP.NET_SessionId=vpt0f3m4jp2gwghm1mmrxyhm; path=/; HttpOnly
Set-Cookie:ARRAffinity=ccebcfbd458447f3ab209749a770ad1f93d4b4c907a7cac9ef717d5fbf543fe3;Path=/;Domain=xxx
X-AspNet-Version:4.0.30319
X-Powered-By:ASP.NET
```

But nothing is stored in the cookies storage of Chrome.

Could it came from the

```
Expires:-1
```

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 3):

I guess your C# backend runs at a different port than your Angular application. Cookies are not shared among different ports of the same host. Chrome displays cookies valid for the current tab URL, which is the Angular application. So you cannot see your backend cookies there.

You can check your headers of XHR requests from the Angular application to the C# backend, they should contain the specified cookies (ASP.NET_SessionId, ARRAffinity).

Comment: It's even more complicated: I'm running my angular app in localhost and the back end in Azure. But I understand the point, so how could I save these cookies in my Angular App ? Doing it he hard way with ngx-cookie ?

Comment: So it's the same situation - different hosts don't share cookies.

Comment: Why do you need the cookies from Azure in your Angular app?

Comment: To retrieve a session in backend.

Comment: The backend session is automatically maintained, because cookies are always attached to your requests. You should not need them in the Angular app.

Comment: I assume that but it seem that they aren't sent with other requests. It might be because each request (even not related to authentication) send me a set-cookie header, but it's a backend problem not a front.

Comment: Thanks a lot @JánHalaša! My cookies weren't attached to the headers due to the fact that I was running the front end on port 4200 and the back end on port 3000.

Comment: Any solution for that ?