# .NET Core 2.0 Web Api - cookies

Tags: c#, .net, cookies, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I am using .NET Core 2.0 Web Api and I am trying to set some values to cookies and later get those values. Here is the method for creating new cookie: (solution taken straight from https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/asp-net-core-working-with-cookie/)

```
protected void SetCookie(string key, string value, int expireTime = 30)
{
    var option = new CookieOptions
    {
        Expires = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(expireTime)
    };

    Response.Cookies.Append(key, value, option);
}
```

Here is the method for getting cookie value:

```
string GetCookie(string key)
{
    return Request.Cookies[key];
}
```

Request.Cookies is always empty (has 0 elements). Could you tell me what I am doing wrong?

Additional informations: On the front-end side I am using Angular 5 (front-end app sits on http://localhost:4200/ and back-end app sits on http://localhost:5000/). But for now I want to save cookie and get cookie just on the backend side.

Comment: Can you see the cookie in the browser tools?

Comment: @Crowcoder cannot find saved cookie in chrome.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43515730/c-sharp-webapi-angular-4-set-cookie-doesnt-save-cookies

Comment: Then you should focus on the set cookie part.